# image background on text div

Tags: html, css

i am making email template, and i want to set one image as background and few text on that image,

but i am not able to get this

i tired to put 2 div and 1 div is image and another div on it, but not get the solution

```
<div style="padding-top: 30px; font-size: 14px; font-family: futuraltbook; height: 500px;">
    <div style="width: 100%; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
        <img src="http://beautifullinux.com/web/wallpaper/SolarisExpressBuild69/images/di-scurve-gray.png" style="height: 500px; margin-left: 10%; margin-right: 10%; width: 500px;" alt="Circle_logo_90.png">
    </div>
    <div style="width: 100%; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; margin-left: 20%; margin-right: 20%;">         
    </div>
</div>
```

what i tired is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/55PFz/)

and yes, i need to set **inline css**. without any urls for image

Comment: Personally I would avoid background images in HTML emails, as it's more trouble than it's worth. And you might want to consider using `<table>`s instead of `<div>`s for the structure of the email.

Comment: You should try Mailchimp, it's awesome.

Comment: in css background-image: url(imgurl);

Comment: First of all as @NickR told its better to use tables for email template. Also I have to tell you that outlook does not support background image either in <tr> or <td>. good luck.

Comment: so there is no way to set background image? i already used table element as main body

Answer (score 1):

Check this out. Hope this is what you are looking for.

http://jsfiddle.net/55PFz/6/

I removed the first div and added the following to the second div

```
background-image:url('http://beautifullinux.com/web/wallpaper/SolarisExpressBuild69/images/di-scurve-gray.png'); background-size:100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [css background image](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp) in your div style.

Example: `background-image:url('paper.gif');`

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your fiddle ..
please have a look.. use `postion:absolute` and `top` properties...

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/55PFz/5/)

Comment: @vir dont mind, but may be I have used absolute position in email template in past..

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/55PFz/7/ 
http://jsfiddle.net/55PFz/9/ 
http://jsfiddle.net/55PFz/10/

Do you want this? set the Background in css

```
background: url('http://beautifullinux.com/web/wallpaper/SolarisExpressBuild69/images/di-scurve-gray.png');
```

Comment: you have to set an background or you work with css `position: absolute;`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem was with your nesting and you should have used a background-image. It's possible to do it by your method but here is the working code, you just need to adjust the padding on the text and you're good to go.

```
<div style="padding-top: 30px; font-size: 14px; font-family: futuraltbook; height: 500px;">
        <div style="width: 100%; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; background-image: url('http://beautifullinux.com/web/wallpaper/SolarisExpressBuild69/images/di-scurve-gray.png'); margin-right: 10%; margin-left: 10%; width: 500px; height: 500px;">


            <div style="width: 100%; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; margin-right: 20%;">
                <p align="left" style="font-family: 'Segoe UI'; font-size: 20px;">Dear viral,</p>
                <p align="left" style="font-family: 'Segoe UI'; font-size: 20px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; On behalf of xxxxxx,Welcome to the world of Personal Branding.Your registration is complete and you are now ready to create your account on the platfrom to Build the Brand that matters.</p>
                <p align="left" style="font-family: 'Segoe UI'; font-size: 20px;">Please <a href="http://192.168.1.9/Default.aspx?keyb=ddd" target="_blank">Click Here</a>to begin creating your Brand.</p>
                <p align="left" style="font-family: 'Segoe UI'; font-size: 20px;">Congratulations!</p>
                <p align="left" style="font-family: 'Segoe UI'; font-size: 20px;">
                    Sincerely,
                    <br>Team xxx
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```